# Как при запросе определенной папки,открывалось содержимое определенного файла?

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется определенный путь `http://site.ru/img/blalaala`,где `blabla` является неизвестным файлом и его нет на сервере.Исходя из этого,что нужно прописать  в `.htaccess` чтобы при открытии данного пути как с дополнительным параметром\так и без `blabla` открывался определенный PHP скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, Вам надо что-то типа этого:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^img(/.*)?$ /404.html [L]
```

Здесь происходит перенаправление с любого адреса внутри `img` и  с самого `img` на `/404.html`.

Если же нужно, чтобы перенаправление работало только для ***отсутствующих*** на сервере файлов, то правило должно быть несколько другим:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^img(/.*)?$ /404.html [L]
```